# Is there any way to disable Skyrim's Auto-aim with bows?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm getting miffed with archery in Skyrim. I'm used to arcing my shots to hit distant targets, but in Skyrim, there's an automatic arc-correct that means when I aim above a bandit's head... I actually hit the space above his head.

Is there any way to disable the Archery Auto-aim in skyrim?

Comment: I don't necessarily think it's auto aiming, I think the cursor's just off for certain distances. Like close range and long range it hits the target, but mid range it hits above the target (arcing over his head), as sometimes I have to aim at a bandits chest to hit his head.

Comment: @MrSmooth The reason the cursor is off is **because** it is auto-correcting. Distance to target is the determining factor.

Comment: Wait, does this mean that in order to hit where you want, you aim where you want? Always?

Comment: @RavenDreamer according to the answer, it seems that it's actually just got an arc like I said, not auto aim.

Comment: No, there is in fact autoaim. Sometimes when attacking a moving target the arrow will aim even higher and move left or right (depending on the lead)... it always overshoots. Very annoying.

Comment: Autoaim is a slight misnomer here. It's not autoaim in the same sense as an FPS has autoaim. This is shooting so that the arrow lands where your cursor is, rather than it being the vector the arrow leaves the bow with, only to fall in a gravity-induced arc later.  It is autocorrecting the normal behavior in many other games where your arrow is affected by gravity and you have to aim like a real archer would. Autoaim in an FPS effectively changes your aim (in both X and Y directions) to hit a target if you are "close enough".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Open up Skyrim.ini in your MyGames/Skyrim folder.

Search for [Combat]
Add one or both of the following lines:

```
f1PArrowTiltUpAngle=0.0
f3PArrowTiltUpAngle=0.0
```

The first line is for first person. The second line is for third person.

Source: http://www.reddit.com/r/skyrim/comments/m8pv2/bow_auto_aim/c2z1omo

Comment: What are the defaults for this? I changed mine and decided I don't like it, but mine didn't have it to begin with, I had to add it, so I don't know what the default was.

Comment: @MrSmooth simply removing it should set it back to the default, no?

Comment: @RavenDreamer I doubt it will, because it's not running any new commands, so it won't really be changing anything. I'll give it a go though.

Comment: @RavenDreamer It worked. :)

Comment: anyways, there's the reason you allways should backup a file or comment out the original lines

Comment: Per spookyfx (the author of Duke Patrick's Combat Archery, the Oblivion mod that Skyrim archery is (very loosely) based on), you should set both of those values to 0.7 for the arrow to fire straight through the crosshairs; 0.0 fires a bit low.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a [mod that disables autoaim](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=15301).

Comment: I wonder if this mod works just by setting the values above, in which case I would still recommend a simple ini tweak.

Comment: @Resorath: From what [I've read](http://zemalf.blogspot.com/2011/11/skyrim-archery-tweak.html), the tweaks in Zeno's answer do not actually disable auto-aim, they disable arcing of bows.  To disable autoaim, you need to use `fMagnetismLookingMult=0.0` and `fMagnetismStrafeHeadingMult=0.0`.  Or you can just download this mod.